# Is the improper integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\cot x}\, dx$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Is the improper integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\cot x} \,dx$ convergent?  I am unable to use any kind of comparison test or anything.

Comment: Yes it is convergent. See the definition of beta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential problem of convergence is as $x \to 0^+$, in this case, by Taylor expansion we have
$$
\sqrt{\cot x} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{x}}
$$ which converges near $0^+$.

Comment: i.e. $\lim_{x \to 0+}\dfrac{\cot x}{\dfrac 1 x}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\dfrac{\sqrt {\cot x}}{\dfrac 1{\sqrt x}}=1$ so the integral convergence by limit comparison test . Right ?

Comment: @user228169 Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ is bounded near the origin, so you can estimate

$$\sqrt{\cot x} \lesssim \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

where the implicit constant can actually be computed as $1$ (although that's much more than what's actually necessary).

Comment: i.e. $\lim_{x \to 0+}\dfrac{\cot x}{\dfrac 1 x}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\dfrac{\sqrt {\cot x}}{\dfrac 1{\sqrt x}}=1$ so the integral convergence by limit comparison test . Right ?

Comment: @user228169 The limit comparison test is a technique for testing the convergence of *series*, not integrals. Just use a direct comparison.

Comment: It can also be used to check convergence of improper integrals . http://math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf